# Can Blocs and Cubits be used Interchangeably?

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I have been working with Blocs and I always navigate in the same way:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
  return BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => MovieListBloc(),
    child: MovieListView(),
   );
}))
```

And now, I'm using a Cubit in a similar way, but getting the error on navigate about "Could not find the correct Provider above BlocBuilder.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
  return BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => MovieListCubit(),
    child: MovieListView(),
   );
}))
```

Am I missing something here, why can't they be used interchangeably?

I swapped the Bloc for a Cubit, and now I can't navigate.

Comment: Please provide more details. Does the error include a stack trace?  What does your code look like where the error actually occurs? Probably where you use BlocBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

i dont't know is it the good wah or no, but instead use `BlocProvider()` to push cubit with context, you can use `BlocProvider.value()`. On other page, wrap the widget with BlocBuilder to use the service in the Bloc/CUbit Class